# how to save data to my custom column in customer_address_entity

Tags: magento2, event-observer

i have made custom column called `coord` in `customer_address_entity` using db_schema.xml

```
<!-- add coordinate to customer address entity -->
<table name="customer_address_entity" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Customer Address Entity">
  <column xsi:type="text" name="coord" nullable="true" comment="Coordinate"/>
</table>
```

to save the data i make an observer but the data won't save to my new column coord, while if i try to save it to vat_request_date, it works
[image]

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $address = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
        $coordinate = $this->_request->getParam('coordinate', '');

        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/debug.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);

        $logger->info('Coordinate: ' . $coordinate);

        if ($coordinate) {
            $address->setCoord($coordinate);
            $address->setVatRequestDate($coordinate);
            $logger->info('Data : ' . print_r($address->getData(), true));
        }
    }
```

it successfully writes the value of coordinate on the log file

```
[coord] => -6.198619001508404,106.81663381349182
[vat_request_date] => -6.198619001508404,106.81663381349182
```

this is the events.xml

```
<event name="customer_address_save_before">
  <observer name="lime_courier_set_latlong" instance="Lime\Courier\Observer\SaveLatlongAddressSaveObserver" />
</event>
```

Comment: try it like this - $address->setData('coord',$coordinate);

Comment: Already tried that, but doesn't work. So i decided to use extension attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface;

class AddressSaveBeforeObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
protected $addressRepository;

public function __construct(AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository)
{
    $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
}    

public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $address = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
    $coordinate = $this->_request->getParam('coordinate', '');

    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/debug.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);

    $logger->info('Coordinate: ' . $coordinate);

    if ($coordinate) {
        $address->setCoord($coordinate);
        $address->setVatRequestDate($coordinate);
        $logger->info('Data : ' . print_r($address->getData(), true));
    }
     $address->setCoord($coordinate);
    $address->setVatRequestDate($coordinate);
    $this->addressRepository->save($address);
}
```

after applying all Magento commands for compile and deploy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i already use extension attributes to save my coordinate :)
Thank you again

Comment: thanks if you want any solution in magento 2 so please tell I will try.